# Ruby array strange behaviour

Tags: ruby, arrays

I misunderstand Array behaviour

When i created this matrix

```
matrix, cell = [], []; 5.times { cell << [] } # columns
3.times { matrix << cell } # lines
matrix
sample_data = (0..5).to_a
matrix[1][2] = sample_data.clone
matrix.each { |line| puts "line : #{line}" }
```

I have this result

```
line : [[], [], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [], []]
line : [[], [], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [], []]
line : [[], [], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [], []]
```

Instead the expected result

```
line : [[], [], [], [], []]
line : [[], [], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [], []]
line : [[], [], [], [], []]
```

What wrong ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with your line:

```
3.times { matrix << cell }
```

You are using the same object `cell` as the three rows of `matrix`.

The key is that `Array` is a mutable object. Even if you modify it, its identity does not change. The three occurences of `cell` are pointing to the same instance (object). If you access and modify it through one occurence of it, the other occurences will reflect that change.

If you change this line to:

```
3.times { matrix << cell.dup }
```

then you will get the desired result.

Comment: Or since cell is empty just use a new [] instead of specifying cell...  `3.times { matrix << [] }`

Answer (score 2):

You're putting the same object (cell) into the matrix three times.

this will fix your bug:

```
3.times { matrix << cell.clone } # lines
```

...but you might want to explain what problem you're trying to solve with this code, as there may be better ways...